# wget: Download files with filename from list of urls using wget

Tags: shell, awk, wget

I have a file music.txt with audios to download, looking like this:

```
http://somehow/music/hexfilename1.mp3 1.mp3    
http://somehow/music/hexfilename2.mp3 2.mp3
http://somehow/music/hexfilename3.mp3 3.mp3
http://somehow/music/hexfilename4.mp3 4.mp3
```

I just want to download the mp3 files, and save as specified names. For instance, download from http://somehow/music/hexfilename1.mp3, we will save as 1.mp3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this is an easy work, but there may be 2 situations:

1. If your `music.txt` is like that in your answer, with url being the first group, and output file being the second, then you can use the following command:

   ```
   IFS="\n"
   for line in $(cat music.txt)
   do
       url=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $1 }')
       out=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $2 }')
       wget "$url" -O "$out"
   done
   ```
2. For the other situation, you just don't need that much script and simply use a `for` loop to go thru each line and pass the parameters to `wget`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For me, that did not work. I needed to add this in the beginning:
`IFS=$'\n'`

Comment: @demianh I was probably wrong. It seems like bash only has the `IFS` variable while `FS` is actually from `awk`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can `read` them into variables using a `while` loop with `read`:

`while read a b; do wget -O "$b" "$a"; done < music.txt`